# r Shiny reactive data with for loop

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm trying to create a small Shiny app that takes in data from Pokemon Go and spits out the best raid counters.  However, I am not getting the reactivity of the data right.  It cannot find the dataframe "newData" anywhere.  This works perfectly until I add the reactive part, getData=reactive({ #code })
Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(RCurl)
library(png)
library(knitr)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  #Read in advantages chart
  url1<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defense031/ST590_Proj2_PoGo/master/PoGoAdvantageChart.csv"
  advantages<-read.csv(quote="",text=getURL(url1),header=TRUE)
  row.names(advantages)<-advantages[,1]
  colnames(advantages)[20]<-"noType2"

  #Read in Individual Pokemon Data
  url2<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defense031/ST590_Proj2_PoGo/master/PoGoIndividualData.csv"
  pogo<-read.csv(text=getURL(url2),header=TRUE)
  newDPS<-rep(0,length(pogo$Pokemon))
  fastAdv<-rep(0,length(pogo$Pokemon))
  chargeAdv<-rep(0,length(pogo$Pokemon))
  totAdv<-rep(0,length(pogo$Pokemon))
  pogo<-cbind(pogo,newDPS,fastAdv,chargeAdv,totAdv)
  newData<-pogo

  #Create title page
  output$titleText<-renderUI({
    text<-paste0("Best Pokemon Go Raid Counters against of ",str_to_title(input$bossName))
    h3(text)
  })

  #Pokemon Go image
  #url3<-"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/defense031/ST590_Proj2_PoGo/master/Pokemon_GO_logo.svg.png"
  #output$pogoLogo<-renderPlot({
    #readPNG(getURLContent(url3))
    #dev.off()
  #})

getData<- reactive({
  #Code to find type1 of raid boss
  bossType1<-as.character(pogo[which(pogo$Pokemon==input$bossName)[1],2])
  #Code to find type2 of raid boss
  bossType2<-ifelse(as.character(pogo[which(pogo$Pokemon==input$bossName)[1],3])=="","noType2",as.character(pogo[which(pogo$Pokemon==input$bossName)[1],3]))
  #boss advantages chart for raid boss
  bossAdvantages<-advantages[c(bossType1,bossType2)]

  #Initialize vector to catch fastType, fastAdv, chargeType

  for(i in 1:length(newData$Pokemon)){
    #Find fast type advantage for each Pokemon
    newData$fastAdv[i]<-bossAdvantages[as.character(newData$FastType[i]),bossType1]*bossAdvantages[as.character(newData$FastType[i]),bossType2]
    #Find charge type advantage for each Pokemon
    newData$chargeAdv[i]<-bossAdvantages[as.character(newData$ChargedMoveType[i]),bossType1] * bossAdvantages[as.character(newData$ChargedMoveType[i]),bossType2]
    #Find DPS Modifier for each Pokemon
    newData$totAdv[i]<-mean(c(newData$chargeAdv[i],newData$fastAdv[i]))
    newData$newDPS[i]<-newData$DPS[i]*totAdv[i]
    newData
  }
  #end getData()
})


#Create plot
  output$DPSPlot<-renderPlot({
    newData<-getData()
    g+geom_point(aes(x=as.character(newData$Type1),y=newData$newDPS))
  })

#Create output of observations    
  output$DPStable <- renderTable({
    newData<-getData()
  })

})
```

Comment: put `newData` outside the `for` loop in `getData`.

Comment: I do at the beginning.  Right after the #Read in individual pokemon data

Comment: can you include the actual error mesg?

Comment: ERROR: object 'newData' not found;
I also tried moving the first two chunks where I define the URLs and pull the data to the outside of the shiny function, but that did not work either.

Comment: Figured out that newData was not being called properly in the UI and the code was failing because of that.  Still, now in the ggplot part it says col y must be 1d atomic vector or list;

even though is.atomic(newData)=TRUE....still failing